# How to Create A file on Disk

Tags: c#

i am working on a pc 192.168.2.200
i have made a simple C# Windows application on 192.168.2.200

I want to Create a Text File on D: of a Network PC whose IP is **192.168.2.201** and **UserName is abc** and **Password is 123**  by C# code in Windows Application
How i Will Create file on Network PC

any one can Help me

Answer (score 3):

```
  System.IO.File.Create(@"D:\myfile.txt");
```

**OR**

```
  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\myfile.txt","Hello this is my File");
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows application or not, you'd use the same technique.  If you don't care what the format is, but want to use it as an input file that you read/write from, then you might want to look into `XmlSerializer`, along with a custom class that you write (with username/password/IP properties).

Here is a simple tutorial on XML serialization:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization

If you want a custom format, and only want to write to it (such as a log file), then you can do this:

```
var file = System.IO.File.Create("file.txt");
var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file);
writer.WriteLine("fjkldsaf");
```

Or use the overload for `StreamWriter` that takes a filename:

```
var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("otherfile.txt");
writer.WriteLine("some text");
```

Keep in mind that writing a password in clear text onto your hard drive is not very secure (same with clear-text over the network, though I know you're not asking about that).

Make sure you either call `Dispose` or `Close` on your file streams when you're done with them.  You can stick them in a `using` block to do this automatically (even if an exception is accidentally thrown in your file writing code).

```
using(var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("otherfile.txt"))
{
  writer.WriteLine("some text");
}
```

Comment: Thanks HI symply i can create a file ob my PC i am working on a pc 192.168.2.200 i have made a siple C# application on 192.168.2.200 and workin on this and i have to write a text file on other Network PC whose IP is 192.168.2.201 and UserName is abc and Password is 123

Comment: @Nagendra: If you want to make clarifications to your question, please edit the question itself.  Not sure if you're asking additional things here, or just clarifying about the whole clear-text password over the network thing.  If you have additional questions about what I wrote, can you ask them again?

Comment: @ Merlyn Morgan-Graham : ok sir i have Edited Question